# How to config web-hook endpoint from a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks

I want to control the choice of endpoints for my webhook based on the value in a variable. I have my hook, and logic, working but I cannot find a way to control how to choose which endpoint to select. I would like to choose from three different endpoints based on the value of 'NumOfClassesBooked'. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

```
    var post_options = {
        hostname: 'webhook.site',
        path: '/fc6d1598-268d-4cd0-8e26-e65f7a5b859b',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/json'
          }
    };    
    
    // Set up the request
    var post_req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
      });
    });
   
    // post the data
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();

    //choose endpoint
    function whichHookToSendTo(NumOfClassesBooked) {

    if (NumOfClassesBooked == "1") {  } 
    else if (NumOfClassesBooked == "4") {  } 
    else if (NumOfClassesBooked == "8") {  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could keep a map of urls and numOfClassesBooked:

```
const webhooks = {
  1':' 'url_one',
  2':' 'url_two',
  ...
}
```

Then use the numOfClassesBooked variable to select the right url:

```
const url = webhooks[numOfClassesBooked]

// post the data
post_data.path = url
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```